Redemption of preferred shares from the issuer
Why the issuer has motivation to redeem preferred shares at par value when they would otherwise trade (on the basis of dividends,maturity and required rate of return) above par value ?
For me this does not make sense unless the issuer is obliged to redeem these shares at market price at maturity and he believes that these market prices would be higher than par value. Otherwise he can just wait and pay par value at maturity. There is no reason to pay a price above par value.
Can you help me please?

Voting to close as there's not one (or even a few) reasons for this in general - it would always be situation-specific.

Do you have a few examples of companies that did this?

Preferred shares get paid before common stock, by design; that's why they are worth more. See many online discussions about how the difference plays out, eg https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/preferredstock.asp

A company might redeem a preferred if interest rates are below the stock's yield, allowing them to issue another preferred at a lower yield.

@keshlam - A company doesn't redeem a preferred stock because " A preferred shares get paid before common stock"

@BobBaerker is correct. Only when a company goes into bankruptcy or disorderly liquidation does the seniority of securities become relevant. In dissolution, the priority of paying back creditors/investors is senior bonds, junior debentures if any (these are bonds too), convertible bonds, preferred stock, then at the end, if there's any money remaining, it goes to holders of common stock.


Issuers typically call their preferred stock for one of two reasons. First, the issuer could simply elect to avoid making future dividend payments if they have the necessary funds. This would be similar to paying off an outstanding loan early if you had enough money in savings. Second, and more commonly, the issuer can “refinance” their preferred stock.

https://app.achievable.me/study/finra-series-7/learn/preferred-stock-features-callable
